# Move a body from point A(x1, 0) to B(x2, 0) with velocity v

Tags: libgdx, position, move

Using libgdx how can I move a body from point *A(x1, 0)* to *B(x2, 0)* with velocity *v*? I want to stop that body exactly in B.

Comment: Your question is kind of vague. By body, do you mean a Box2d physics body, or just some generic sprite? Are you using scene2d or not, and is this body an actor?

Comment: Yes, this body is an actor in fact. I managed to set the velocity in the good direction and set it back to 0 when needs to be stopped but sometimes does not stop at right position.

Answer (score 0):

That's easy. Involve current position (x) variable and set it's value to x1 at start (constructor). Every frame draw your body at x,0 coords. With every cycle (frame) add v to x and check is x >= x2. If it is then set v to 0.

Comment: I am doing something similar, but the body(actor) does not stop always on the right position. Sometimes goes with few pixels after.

Comment: Well, let's say your speed is10px per frame. That means that in one frame you can be like 4px from the x2, position is valid and you continue moving. Next frame you'll be 6px after x2, you stop moving, but you are still 6px after. So, when you reach (or pass) x2 you have to set x to x2, not only speed to zero. Make sure that you do this right after moving (adding speed to x) so you'll set x to x2 before you do drawing so you'll avoid one frame glitch.

Comment: Thanks MilanG for the advice, I will check.